# Is it possible to provide an implicit conversion from an Iterable[T] to an Iterable[U]?

Tags: scala, type-conversion

Given some case classes `Foo(x: Int)` and `Bar(x: Int)`, an (implicit) function `f1` that converts `Foo => Bar` is it possible to achieve the following:

```
val foos: List[Foo] = List(Foo(1), Foo(2))
def myFunction(bar: List[Bar]) = ???

myFunction(foos) // Here foos should be implicitly converted from List[Foo] to List[Bar]
```

Comment: What about writing the implicit function to convert from Iterable[T] to Iterable[U] using the implicit function `f1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for?

```
scala> case class Foo(x: Int) {}
defined class Foo

scala> case class Bar(y: Int) {}
defined class Bar

scala> import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.language.implicitConversions

scala> implicit def f2b(foos: List[Foo]): List[Bar] = foos.map(foo => new Bar(foo.x))
f2b: (foos: List[Foo])List[Bar]

scala> def barIt(bs: List[Bar]): Unit = bs.foreach(bar => println(bar.y))
barIt: (bs: List[Bar])Unit

scala> val foos = List(new Foo(59), new Foo(2), new Foo(99))
foos: List[Foo] = List(Foo(59), Foo(2), Foo(99))

scala> barIt(foos)
59
2
99
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the implicit conversion from a `Foo` to a `Bar`, the following will give a simple implicit conversion for the lists:

```
implicit def foos2bars(foos: List[Foo]): List[Bar] = foos.map(f => f:Bar)
```